# syncing two database schemas

Tags: sql-server

I have a source database and a destination database with common tables. Is there any online tool that will sync the schema of tables in the source to destination ? Both databases are in MSSQL

Comment: is that a paid version? Is there an open source alternative?

Comment: I don't know any open source alternative, since its a sophisticated piece of software for a complex task. RedGate is your tool of choice. 
Remember if you DO find a freeware, and if you DO find any online tool, you will have to grant it ADMIN rights to both your databases, which one might consider a huge security issue. 
Better run a tool locally.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ideas:

1. Use Replication: http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication
2. Use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) in an import/export script to semi-automate it